# LOTUS and Adam's Law Nomenclature

Tags: probability, statistics, soft-question

I want  to go a little deeper into statistics than what my educational institution did. In [Blitzstein](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VmkAAGOYCTORq1wxSQqy255qLJjTNvBI/edit) I met concepts like LOTUS: The Law of the Unconsious Statistician (Section 4.5), which I had not heard of.  I realized after some reading that was a property covered in my course (without being given any specific name):
$$E[g(x)]= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} g(x)p(x)$$

The book also talks about Adam's Law, which, in the discrete case, is mathematical expectation. In discrete probability, my teachers defined "mathematical expectation" as
$$E[X]= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x p(x)$$

There was no mention of Adam. The book actually has Eve's Law. But I haven't got around to looking at it.

I don't mind learning new terminology, but I don't like learning a bunch of fancy jargon either. Are these names specific to Harvard, or colleges in the US. In general, is knowing these names important?

Just for context: The book seems to really like these "names" for properties as if they were THE way to talk about them. Like the "quadratic formula" is known to pretty much everybody.

Comment: LOTUS is a name no one uses. Everyone knows that $E[g(x)] = \sum g(x)p(x)$, so there is no need to repeatedly reference LOTUS when using the above elementary formula. And terminology in standard probability (i.e. the topics that are in every textbook) is standard, so you do not need to worry about learning so many terms.

Comment: Also, by the way, $E[X] = \sum xp(x)$ is a definition, $E[g(x)] = \sum g(x)p(x)$ is a formula. Ironically, you are confusing/conflating the two in your post!

Comment: It's been sometime since I did the course. Will update my post.

Comment: <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician>

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I have seen the wikipedia page. The question was whether everyone uses these terms (specifically my college teachers didn't - and I wanted to check the genera trend) given that they didn't teach me anything wrong.....